# Can't Install latest Tensorflow versions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I tried installing Tensorflow using the pip install tensorflow, but I got this error code instead. I'll really use y'alls help

ERROR: Wheel 'termcolor' located at C:\users\user\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\b6\0d\90\0d1bbd99855f99cb2f6c2e5ff96f8023fad8ec367695f7d72d\termcolor-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl is invalid.

Comment: Perhaps try to clear your pip cache? Or append `--no-cache-dir`

Comment: Please follow the instructions mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) to install `Tensorflow` as per your system OS.